# How to change enum values in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a enum property in my mongoose collection that was initial defined as `const actions = ['a', 'b', 'c']` I have a requirement to change it to add addition actions `const actions = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` to the enum but when I try to use the additional values i.e. `action = 'e'` I get a validation error `"Model validation failed: action: 'e' is not a valid enum value for path 'action'."`

My question is how do I add additional values to the enum to a mongo collection in mongoose already in production.

```js
mongoose.model('Model', new Schema({
  action: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: actions,
    immutable: true
  }}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to inconsistent between current and previous data, Mongoose will try to validate current data (old schema) with the new one, even when you don't modify anything and cause a validation error.  In my case, I force Mongoose to save with new schema by using flag `validateBeforeSave`.

For example:

```
const savedProduct = await currentProduct.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
```